# Tuple / array equivalent of Pick utility

Tags: typescript

How can one produce the equivalent of `Pick` but for arrays/tuples:

```js
type Foo = [ a: 'a', b: 'b',c: 'c']
type Bar= Pick<Foo,1|2>
const bar:Bar = ['b','c'] // should be valid as items 1 and 2 are selected
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBtKBDAXFA5B3AGigCMcAiE8wgYx1xtwF0AoUSKAIQwCcUAFAJY0A1gB54cQgEYAPgCYAfCxpwAdgGdgpXlm49kaXCSINmLIA)

Comment: `type Foo = [ a: 'a', b: "b",c: 'c']` is a strange line, I don't think I've seen that syntax. Did you want a plain tuple with `type Foo = ['a', "b", 'c'];`?

Comment: ^ It’s a labeled tuple (see ts4.0 release notes I think)

Comment: Given an input of an array, or a tuple, it should return the picked elements (based on their numerical position in the array or tuple).

Comment: @CertainPerformance - typo by me - I've edited the question.

Comment: Note that this isn't `Pick`, since that would presumably be a *sparse array* like `[, 'b', 'c']`.  You're *re-keying* elements, which is outside the scope of `Pick`.

Comment: I'm naming this `FilterTupleByIndex` instead of `Pick`.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOLnrN) meet your needs?  There are almost certainly lots of edge cases (I think optional tuple elements are not supported) so please test and if you find something you don't like then [edit] the question to show the use case.  Anyway, if it meets your needs I could write up an answer; let me know.